# Do I need to have the passport when my domestic flight halts in an international airport?

Tags: air-travel, passports, india, paperwork, domestic-travel

I want to know whether it is mandatory to carry my passport during domestic travel too and at what conditions do I need one!

Comment: What country are you asking about? India?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about that.

Comment: Yes we need more details. Where does this flight go? Where does it stop? What airline?

Answer (score 6):

Generally, no, a passport is not required for domestic travel.  International airports are designed to handle domestic flights without requiring travelers to pass through immigration control.

In many cases domestic travelers need to present some form of ID, however, and anyone who has a passport but lacks any other acceptable form of non-passport identification would have to use the passport.  This is frequently the case for foreign tourists taking a domestic flight in a country they're visiting.

If you are concerned about a specific flight, you should ask the airline operating that flight.  They can tell you what documents will be required.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you don't necessarily need to have a passport for domestic flight halts within India if you're an *Indian Citizen*.

Many airports in India have a common terminal for use of both domestic and international flights, you can get along easily with ID proof like *Aadhar Card, PAN Card,Driving License or Election Card* etc.

I had a flight from Chandigarh(Chd Intl. Airport) to Mumbai(Chhatrapati Shivaji Intl. Airport) with halt at Delhi(Indira Gandhi Intl. Airport). Showing Aadhar Card or similar ID proof to the guards along with tickets/boarding pass is more than sufficient.

Comment: okkk...It is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your domestic flight is stopping at an international airport, you should not need your passport in **MOST** cases, as long as the entire aircraft was meant for a domestic route.

Exception?

- Some international flights fly a domestic leg as it hops to pick up passengers, It occasionally may have a few domestic passengers on board, they will be required to show passport.

Thumb rule:

- If exiting at an international airport, check with the airline to ask if you are expected to go though immigration on landing.